# How can I fix this problem booting Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: boot, 18.04, live-usb

When I try to boot my laptop with an Ubuntu live USB, my laptop show this error and does not boot :

```
(initramfs) mount: mounting /cow on/root failed: Invalid argument overlay mount failed
```

The laptop has got Windows 10, and I'm trying to boot with a live USB Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, im going to edit

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the changelog of Rufus for version 3.6(https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/blob/master/ChangeLog.txt):

> o Version 3.6 (2019.07.18)
>   Add support for persistent partitions [EXPERIMENTAL]
>   (Note: The above won't work with Ubuntu until Ubuntu bug #1489855 is properly fixed)

You may have enabled persistence while creating the bootable iso. So you can either use a latest non-LTS Ubuntu(19.10 or later) which does not have the bug or edit syslinux.cfg on the usb to remove persistence or recreate the bootable iso with persistence turned off if the option is there.

Comment: Now shows this: graphics initialitation failed. Error setting up gfxboot. Boot:  Could not allocate memory.

Comment: You can try this,not sure it will work.Go to /isolinux/isolinux.cfg and delete the line "ui gfxboot bootlogo".If you get undefined video mode xxx error go to /boot/grub/menu.lst and change to "vga=normal".Apparently the issue is fixed in newer versions of the package gfxboot(4.5.22) but Ubuntu uses 4.5.2. If you still get the error add the boot parameters nomodset acpi=off etc else use the mini.iso or newer Ubuntu or Lubuntu/Kubuntu etc.